# Export xls or cvs data Angular 5

Tags: json, node.js, angular5, xlsx

Hi I need export the data of a table in angular5 I'm using the API xls and filesaver this my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

const EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
const EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';

@Injectable()
export class ExportexcelService {

  constructor() { }

  public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
  const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
  const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, 
  SheetNames: ['data'] };
  const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 
  'array' });
  this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
  }
  private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
  const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {type: EXCEL_TYPE});
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear() + '' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '' + 
  today.getDate() + '_';
  var time = today.getHours() + "-" + today.getMinutes() + "-" + 
  today.getSeconds();
  var name = fileName + date + time;
  FileSaver.saveAs(data, name + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
  }
  }
```

the data of table contains rows of date, currency and this code work but the output don't have the correct format on dates and number.

NOTE: the code of the data is in format json and I call where data:Interfacename[];. This interface only contain the name of my variables for example:

- name:string;
- lastname:string;
- age:number;
- etc...